# Segmentation fault while trying to read a file with IO.foreach

Tags: ruby, foreach, termux

I am running Ruby on my phone with Termux to check the number of Zombie processes.

Very weirdly, while trying to read a file with `IO#foreach`:

```
IO.foreach("/proc/#{$$}/status").tap(&:next).next
```

Ruby is crashing with `Segmentation fault`, both in a file and in *irb*.

But I can read the file with:

```
IO.readlines("/proc/#{$$}/status")[1]
```

Both of the codes are working on my PCs.

What's wrong with `foreach`?

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to do here?  It's not clear from your code. What is the expected behavior?

Comment: On linux, the expected behaviour is to get the status of processes. The string returned by `IO.readlines(...)[1]` should contain `"Umask:\t0022\n"` or `"State:\tZ (zombie)\n"`. In case of this program, it shouldn't be a zombie, because it's the current ruby process. I was going to loop through all the files, and count the number of running, sleeping, idle, and zombie processes on GNU/Linux. The actual implementation is here: https://github.com/Souravgoswami/cowspeak/blob/057532a8aaa0020ad4959dd216738aa0bdc9950e/cowspeak#L560 Here I have updated it to `IO.readlines` instead of `IO#foreach`.

Comment: What version of ruby are you running? Also your example code use of `foreach` doesn't reflect anything what you're doing in your blob

Comment: The Ruby version is 2.6.2..2.6.4. This problem happens specifically with the Ruby on Termux, on GNU/Linux (Ruby 2.3..2.7) it runs fine...

Comment: For example https://imgur.com/8ilJskC